# best practice for presentation layer (wicket) and business logic (spring) communication

Tags: java, spring, communication, wicket

i want to develop a business application with wicket for the presentation layer and spring/hibernate core for business and data layer.

the presentation layer and business layer gonna run on diffenent physical machines.

what are my possibilities for communication/business function calls betweent presentation and business layer and what are your experiences with that solutions?

The solution has to be very scalable and high-performance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you want to use two separate machines for that. Better put the presentation and the business in same app and use 2 or more machines for scalability.

This reminds me of the old days of EJB 1-2 when people wanted to put the business on different machines, without a business need to do that. This option has the cost of network latency and the extra layer of serializing/deserializing.

If your need is legit though, you might do the communication with JMS, which is a standard, and Spring framework offers JMS support.

Comment: hm thanx victor. I am thinking about using JAX-WS, but jms seems to be a good option.

most likely there will be more than one frontend implementation, that uses the business layer.

Answer (score 0):

Spring provides a number of ways of exposing and utilising remote services, check the [reference documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/remoting.html)

You might also want to investigate messaging as an alternative for RPC style remote services. The seminal reference on the subject is [Enterprise Integration Patterns](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/)

Comment: thank your for your links, they are very helpful. i am going to check the alternatives.